# python - iterating list of dictionaries and unpacking

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, argument-unpacking

Given a flat list of simple dictionaries

```
lst = [{'key1': 1}, {'key2': 2}, {'key3': 3}]
```

I'd like to find the dict that yields the minimum value evaluated using a method not detailed here.
My first idea was to iterate the list to check dict by dict, but this fails:

```
for k, v in [x.items() for x in lst]:
    print(k, v)
```

results ValueError (as well as using a generator instead of the list):

```
for k, v in [x.items() for x in lst]:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

However,

```
for x in lst:
    for k, v in x.items():
        print(k, v)
```

yields

```
key1 1
key2 2
key3 3
```

As expected. I assume all approaches work as intended (unless PEBKAC), but why doesn't it work using the list comprehension? Could someone enlighten me?

Edit: I use python 3 and I know items() yields a dict_view but I don't see why the logic doesn't work.

Comment: if you unpack `x.items()` it returns three lists with tuples of two (key & value) inside. If `x.items()` was a present, you'd have to unpack another layer of gift wrap paper. Try `x.items()[0]` in your list comprehension!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing a level of iteration.

Normally, dicts have more than one key/value pair. `dict.items()` converts the entire dictionary into a sequence of tuples in the form `(key, value)`. In your case, each dictionary has just one item, but the result of `items()` is still a tuple of tuples.

If you print the result of `[x.items() for x in lst]` you'll see that the result is a list of `dict_view` items; each one of those can itself be iterated.

Comment: Right, as it is clear - for me as well - from the working solution. I guess I wanted to omit the [0] suggested by @offeltoffel, seems a bit like a magic number. I'll use the non-comprehansion version for readibility.

Comment: Each tuple of k and v is wrapped as the only item in another list when trying to unpack your `lst`. What's the index of the only element in any list? It's `0`. No magic, just logic. I agree though that readability is more important than short codes, so you should implement whatever you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of taking the first element of your `dict_view` you can add one level of indentation (as @DanielRoseman suggested) in your list comprehension:

```
for k, v in [(k, v) for x in lst for (k, v) in x.items()]:
  print(k, v)
```

yield

```
key1 1
key2 2
key3 3
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try to unpack your `lst` step by step to understand how it is constructed.

```
>>> in: lst[0].items()
>>> out: [('key1', 1)]
```

Your result (that is equal to your `x.items()` expression in the list comprehension) is **another list** containing your tuple of k and v. The tuple is the element of index 0 in this list (and also the only element at all). So you need to go like

```
for k, v in [x.items()[0] for x in lst]:
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: this won't work, dict_view doesn't support indexing. list(x.items())[0] is the way to go, but looks ugly :-/

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my machine. I use python 2.7 though.

Comment: sure, but this is one of the few things that breaks if you go to 3.x

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over key, value pair of a dictionary like this:-

```
for k, v in dic.items():
    print(k, v)
```

what above code does is to first convert dictionary into a list of tuples which are then unpacked one by one while iterating into k, v just like:-

```
k, v = (k, v) # Tuple unpacking.
```

Now in your case, Consider this code:-

```
z = [x.items() for x in lst]
print(z)
```

Output is

```
[dict_items([('key1', 1)]), dict_items([('key2', 2)]), dict_items([('key3', 3)])]
```

i.e a **list** of lists of tuple.

So, Let us rewrite your code as :-

```
for k, v in z:
    print(k, v)
```

Where z is a list of lists of tuple.
At each iteration, it picks up a list(which contains only one element) from the parent list and then it tries:-

```
k, v = [(key, value)] # a list of only one tuple to be unpacked against two variables and hence the failure.
```

I hope this was helpful.